# Passing a variable to MySQL with Express

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, variables, ejs

```
app.get('/sort',(req, res) => {
var tabelle = req.params.table;
let sql = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY tabelle DESC;";
let query = connection.query(sql, (err, rows) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    res.render('user_index', {
        title : 'CRUD Operation using NodeJS / ExpressJS / MySQL',
        users : rows
    });
  });
});
```

I want that MySQL sorts by the variable tabelle, but i dont know how to do this. Im making a simple CRUD application with more operations like this one, where i sort them. Im using Node.js, Express, ejs and MySQL

Answer (score 1):

Use `?` prevent sql injection

```js
let sql = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY ? DESC;";

let query = connection.query(sql, [tabelle], function(err, results) {
    ...
});
```